# Release apk doesn't update

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, release

Some one can help me, I have a problem when upload a new version of my app, I signed with release certificate but when new version is publishied users can't see "update" option only "open" even they has previous version of app. The problem began when I sign new apks from another laptop, but always using the same certificate.
I tried sign it with previous Gradle version and doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the app version in the gradle and the Google Play Store **ACCEPTED** your new app version, you should just wait 24/48 hours, sometimes it takes just a lot of time to display new uptdates. If you still not find the app update after a few of days just post some screenshots and we'll provide to help you.
**Happy coding!**